# Finding an element node that is buried a few layers down in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to access and display information from this xml file that pertains to the "capabilities" element. However whenever I access the capabilities element it wont return the correct values for the child elements. This is the xml snippet that I am working with.

```
<Conference>
    <ActiveSpeaker>
      <CallId>1</CallId>
    </ActiveSpeaker>
    <Call item="62" maxOccurrence="n">
      <BookingId>15909</BookingId>
      <Capabilities>
        <FECC>
          <Mode>On</Mode>
          <NumberOfPresets>0</NumberOfPresets>
          <NumberOfSources>1</NumberOfSources>
          <Source item="1" maxOccurrence="n">
            <Name>n/a</Name>
            <Options>ptzf</Options>
            <SourceId>1</SourceId>
          </Source>
        </FECC>
        <FarendMessage>
          <Mode>Off</Mode>
        </FarendMessage>
        <Hold>True</Hold>
        <IxChannel>
          <Status>Active</Status>
        </IxChannel>
        <Presentation>True</Presentation>
      </Capabilities>
      <Manufacturer>Tandberg</Manufacturer>
      <MicrophonesMuted>False</MicrophonesMuted>
      <SoftwareID>unknown (new?)</SoftwareID>
    </Call>
    <DoNotDisturb>Active</DoNotDisturb>
    <Line item="1" maxOccurrence="n">
      <Mode>Private</Mode>
    </Line>
    <Multipoint>
      <Mode>CUCMMediaResourceGroupList</Mode>
    </Multipoint>
    <Presentation>
      <CallId>62</CallId>
      <Mode>Receiving</Mode>
    </Presentation>
    <SpeakerLock>
      <CallId>0</CallId>
      <Mode>Auto</Mode>
    </SpeakerLock>
  </Conference>
```

And this is my current code to try and access the elements.

```
                from cp in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf("Capabilities")
                select new
                {
                    Options = (string)cp.Element("Options"),
                    Name = (string)cp.Element("Name"),
                    SourceId = (string)cp.Element("SourceId"),
                    Mode = (string)cp.Element("Mode"),
                    Status = (string)cp.Element("Status")
                };
```

I will occasionally return a result for options, but the other values are always null.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
            from cp in elem.DescendantsAndSelf("Capabilities")
                 select new
                 {
                     Options = (string)cp.Element("FECC").Element("Source").Element("Options"),
                     Name = (string)cp.Element("FECC").Element("Source").Element("Name"),
                     SourceId = (string)cp.Element("FECC").Element("Source").Element("SourceId"),
                     Mode = (string)cp.Element("FECC").Element("Mode"),
                     Status = (string)cp.Element("IxChannel")
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            var results = (from cp in doc.Descendants("Capabilities")
                select new
                {
                    Options = (string)cp.Descendants("Options").FirstOrDefault(),
                    Name = (string)cp.Descendants("Name").FirstOrDefault(),
                    SourceId = (string)cp.Descendants("SourceId").FirstOrDefault(),
                    Mode = (string)cp.Descendants("Mode").FirstOrDefault(),
                    Status = (string)cp.Descendants("Status").FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList();
```